# Classifying a dataset using Naive Bayes

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am trying to classify a dataset of tweets using the Naive Bayes classifier found in the NLTK. However, rather than classifying a single sentence, such as below

```
classifier.classify(toDict("this is good"))
```

I need to have something like this, below.

```
classifier.classify(toDict(tweets))
```

My issue is that rather than classifying one sentence, I need to classify a full dataset. The commented code is what I have already tried.

Rest of my code is below.

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import re
import random
from pandas import DataFrame
from nltk import *
from nltk import classify
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer as w_tokenizer
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

```
def toDict(word):
     return {word : True}
```

```
posDataset = [(tweet_dict, "Positive")
                     for tweet_dict in posModel]

negDataset = [(tweet_dict, "Negative")
                     for tweet_dict in negModel]

trainingDataset = posDataset + negDataset

random.shuffle(trainingDataset)

trainData, testData = trainingDataset[8000:], trainingDataset[:6000]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainData)

#print(classifier.classify(dict((item, True) for item in tweets)))
#classifier.classify()

classifier.classify(toDict("this is good"))
```

'tweets' is a pandas Series, items stored as lists. Image example is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3fjH.png)

Here is the error message I get from running the commented out code.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-957eed734b8a> in <module>
     20 classifier.classify(toDict("this is good"))
     21 
---> 22 print(classifier.classify(dict((item, True) for item in tweets)))
     23 #classifier.classify()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue and your *question*?

Comment: I need to classify the tweets set, I thought it was obvious in first section of the post. Ill edit.

Comment: But what is your *issue*? What you have tried so far, and how it fails? Do you get errors? What are they?

Comment: My issue is that I cant run a full dataset through my classifier, I updated my post the first time you commented. I commented out the code at the bottom which I have tried. The error from the commented code is in the post, I have updated.

Comment: For the future, please keep in mind that "*I can't run it*" is not a valid issue description; a valid issue description includes 1) the full error trace 2) the *minimal* code necessary to reproduce it. See how to create a [mcve]. The fact that you did get an answer this time does not change the argument, I kindly suggest you follow the rules and guidelines to ensure meaningful responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below will give you a generic how-to.

### Creating a test dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["this is a text", "that was a text", "but, you were a text"]})

>>> df
                   text
0        this is a text
1       that was a text
2  but, you were a text
```

### Defining your classification function (example)

```
>>> def classify_by_size(x):
...     size = len(x)
...     if size < 15:
...         return "small"
...     elif size > 15:
...         return "big"
...     return "medium"
...
```

**Note:** The function above would be your classification method

### Classifying

```
>>> df["new_column"] = df["text"].apply(classify_by_size)

>>> df
                   text new_column
0        this is a text      small
1       that was a text     medium
2  but, you were a text        big
```

So, in your case you would have something like:

```
def my_classification(x):
    return classifier.classify(toDict(x))
```

And the call:

```
df["new_column"] = df["text"].apply(my_classification)
```

This might work well for small dataframes.

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for your answer, would this still work with a Pandas Series type of data?

Comment: Yes, in the example above `df["text"]` is a data Series.